# Group By Java 8

Tags: lambda, group-by, java-8

Assume you an Student enrolling to courses

```
Class Student{
  ArrayList<Course> courses;
}
Class Course{
  String id;
  String name;
}
```

How can use groupBy function with java 8 to list of students attending a particular course

Answer (score 4):

As you want to classify the same student to different groups, the `groupingBy` collector is not suitable here (it puts every stream element exactly to one group).

It would be more efficient to create a mutable container (like `HashMap`) and populate it via `forEach`:

```
Map<Course, List<Student>> result = new HashMap<>();
students.forEach(student -> student.courses.forEach(
        course -> result.computeIfAbsent(course, c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(student)));
```

If you want to use `groupingBy` you can group not the students, but student-course pairs, though you would need to perform down stream collection steps:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<Course, List<Student>> result = students.stream()
    .<Map.Entry<Course, Student>>flatMap(
        student -> student.courses.stream()
                          .map(course -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(course, student)))
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Looks kinda ugly. My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library adds some shortcuts for such scenario:

```
Map<Course, List<Student>> result = StreamEx.of(students)
      .cross(s -> s.courses.stream()).invert().grouping();
```

This looks much better, but plain solution still looks better to be (and does not require third-party libraries).

Comment: Thanks Tagir Valeev.That was useful

Comment: The explicit type `<Map.Entry<Course, Student>>` shouldn’t be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I am using the idea from @tagir-valeev answer.
Create a simple class

```
public class CourseStundentPair {
    private Course course;
    private Student student;

    public CourseStundentPair(Course course, Student student) {
        this.course = course;
        this.student = student;
    }
    ...
    }
```

This will make the code more conice and readable.
Just out of convince I added name field to student

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class TestCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student("1", "Student1");
        Student student2 = new Student("2", "Student2");
        Student student3 = new Student("3", "Student3");
        Student student4 = new Student("4", "Student4");
        Course course1 = new Course("c1", "English");
        Course course2 = new Course("c2", "Mathematics");
        Course course3 = new Course("c3", "Literature");
        student1.getCourses().add(course1);
        student1.getCourses().add(course2);
        student1.getCourses().add(course3);

        student2.getCourses().add(course1);
        student2.getCourses().add(course2);
        student3.getCourses().add(course1);

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);
        students.add(student4);

        final Map<Course, List<Student>> courseToStudents = students.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> s.getCourses().stream().map(c -> new CourseStundentPair(c,s)))
            .collect(groupingBy(CourseStundentPair::getCourse,
                                mapping(CourseStundentPair::getStudent, toList())
                    )
            );

       for (Course course :courseToStudents.keySet()){
           System.out.printf("Course %s , Students: %s \n"
                   ,course.getName()
                   ,courseToStudents.get(course).stream().map(Student::getName)
                                    .collect(joining(", ")));
       }

    }
```

The console will output

```
Course English , Students: Student1, Student2, Student3 
Course Literature , Students: Student1 
Course Mathematics , Students: Student1, Student2
```

Note that in eclipse the IDE may complain about compilation error, in Intellij it will work fine.